# Find smaller array within larger array

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, vector

I have a data set composed of a vector of size ~1 000 000. I want to find the indices of where a fixed array is found (when 12 or more NaNs are found consecutively).

Most searches bring up `ismember()` or `intersect()` which do not do the job to my knowledge (would only return where any member of my search array of NaNs is).

I'm aware I could do this in a for loop, however, I have over 20 of these data sets and calculating all of these in this way would take a very long time.

If anyone has a time-inexpensive way of doing this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) for that. Although not documented, this function works for numeric vectors too:

```
>> x = [7 4 5 2 4 5];
>> y = [5 2 4];
>> strfind(x, y)
ans =
     3
```

However, it won't find `NaN`'s. This is consistent with the fact that [two `NaN`'s are not equal to each other](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html#f91-998324):

```
>> x = [7 4 NaN NaN NaN 5];
>> y = [NaN NaN NaN];
>> strfind(x, y)
ans =
     []
```

So if the pattern you want to find consists of `NaN`'s you need to convert to a logical vector first:

```
>> x = [7 4 NaN NaN NaN 5];
>> y = [NaN NaN NaN];
>> xNaN = isnan(x);
>> yNaN = isnan(y);
>> strfind(xNaN, yNaN)
ans =
     3
```

Or in this case you can also use [convolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
>> find(conv(xNaN, yNaN, 'valid')==numel(yNaN))
ans =
     3
```